# Error while save item on database, android studio

Tags: java, android, sql

I have problem when I try put new data.

My code:

ThoughtManager:

```
 public long createThought(Thought thought)  // TWORZE NOWY ELEMENT W BAZIE DANYCH!!!
{
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.INDEXNUMBER, thought.getIndexNumber());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.NAME, thought.getName());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.TIME, thought.getTime());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.DATE, thought.getDate());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.GROUPCODE, thought.getGroupCode());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.IDPRINTFINGER, thought.getIDPrintfinger());
    contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.AMOUNTOFPRESENCE, thought.getAmountOfPresence());

    return db.insert(ThoughtDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

DbHelper:

```
//Zmienne do mojej bazy danych
static final String INDEXNUMBER="indexnumber";
static final String NAME="name";
static final String GROUPCODE="groupcode";
static final String IDPRINTFINGER="idprintfinger";
static final String KEY="_id";
static final String AMOUNTOFPRESENCE="amountofpresence";
static final String DATE="date";
static final String TIME="time";
static final String TABLE_NAME="thought_tbl";
static final String DATABASE_NAME="thought_db.sql"; // nasza baza danych
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // wesja naszej bazy danych

private String QUERY_STRING="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "+KEY
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+ INDEXNUMBER
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + TIME
        + " TEXT, " + DATE + " TEXT, " + GROUPCODE + " TEXT, " + IDPRINTFINGER
        + " TEXT, " + AMOUNTOFPRESENCE
        + " TEXT )";
```

And metod on class when i try add new data:

```
 case R.id.btnAddThought:
            if(requestReply!=null)
            {
                idPrintfinger=requestReply;
            }
            index=etIndex.getText().toString(); // Pobieram z pola tekstowe wpisane znaki i zapisuje je do zmiennej
            name=etName.getText().toString();
            groupcode=etGroup.getText().toString();

            thougt.setIndexNumber(index); // zapisuje w bazie poszczegolne elementy
            thougt.setName(name);
            thougt.setTime(time);
            thougt.setDate(date);
            thougt.setGroupCode(groupcode);
            thougt.setIDPrintfinger(idPrintfinger);
            thougt.setAmountOfPresence(amountOfPresence);

            manager.openForWrite(); // właczma odpcje zpaisywania na DYSK!
            long res=manager.createThought(thougt); // Zapisuje dane na DYSKU!
            if(res!=-1)
            {
               ClearFields();
            }
            break;
```

Here is my Edit LogCat, still have problem with this code problem, propably I blind or sth

```
3-23 18:00:27.084 24591-24591/com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication     

E/SQLiteLog: (1) table thought_tbl has no column named groupcode
03-23 18:00:27.084 24591-24591/com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication      

E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting groupcode=dasdasdada indexnumber=asdasddsdasd time=00:00 amountofpresence=0 idprintfinger=000 date=01.01.1990 name=asdada
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table thought_tbl has no column named groupcode (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO thought_tbl(groupcode,indexnumber,time,amountofpresence,idprintfinger,date,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                                                                                     at com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication.ThoughtManager.createThought(ThoughtManager.java:74)
                                                                                     at com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication.AddThought.onClick(AddThought.java:138)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column '`group`' in your table `thought_tbl`
but you are trying to insert some value for that column.

```
 contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.GROUP, thought.getGroup());
```

Thats why you are getting the `SQLiteException` exception.

Comment: I edit my code, i put the wrong code in ThoughtDbHelper. Could you look again

Comment: Still the same error. You are inserting value for  contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.GROUP, thought.getGroup()); but you have column 'groupcode'

Comment: I changed into my code, but it don;t work ;/ i have groupcode i both of them

Comment: I propably do easy mistake, but i can't got it ;/

Comment: Change  contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.GROUP, thought.getGroup());  to   contentValues.put(ThoughtDbHelper.GROUPCODE, thought.getGroup());

Comment: And still have problem

Comment: Update your logcat  output also after running the updated code.

Comment: The database table is not updated . Uninstall and install the app again, then if it crashes, paste the fresh logs.

Comment: I did it, but still LogCat is the same ;/

Comment: I donno how you are creating your database. But the error says - "table thought_tbl has no column named groupcode "

Comment: Yes i saw that, i look 10 times and i have everywhere groupcode

Comment: Extract your db file from device . use Mozilla firefox sqlitemanager plugin to check your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a column named "group" which is a keyword.

[The SQL standard](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) specifies a huge number of keywords which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object.

Try changing the column name to something else.

Comment: He already changed the column to "groupcode" then also he's facing the issue.